# Dropdown with Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, controls, drop-down-menu

Looking for an open source .net control that functions like this: http://www.obout.com/combobox/cbo_integration_databound_checkboxlist.aspx  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: NOTE: the control fails to be usable if JavaScript is disabled, which may or may not be an issue for what you want to apply it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Javascript but looks like what you're after.

http://lab.arc90.com/2007/07/multiselect.php#examples

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a div element looking similar to a drop down list.

You can use javascript, CSS and HTML for making a div with drop down list like features.

Answer (score 0):

Open source server control that renders CheckBoxList as a drop down:
http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/